# Performance problem transforming JSON data

Tags: json, r

I've got some data in JSON format that I want to do some visualization on.  The data (approximately 10MB of JSON) loads pretty fast, but reshaping it into a usable form takes a couple of minutes for just under 100,000 rows.  I have something that works, but I think it can be done much better.

It may be easiest to understand by starting with my [sample data](http://public.west.spy.net/so/time-series.json.gz).

Assuming you run the following command in `/tmp`:

```
curl http://public.west.spy.net/so/time-series.json.gz \
    | gzip -dc - > time-series.json
```

You should be able to see my desired output (after a while) here:

```
require(rjson)

trades <- fromJSON(file="/tmp/time-series.json")$rows


data <- do.call(rbind,
                lapply(trades,
                       function(row)
                           data.frame(date=strptime(unlist(row$key)[2], "%FT%X"),
                                      price=unlist(row$value)[1],
                                      volume=unlist(row$value)[2])))

someColors <- colorRampPalette(c("#000099", "blue", "orange", "red"),
                               space="Lab")
smoothScatter(data, colramp=someColors, xaxt="n")

days <- seq(min(data$date), max(data$date), by = 'month')
smoothScatter(data, colramp=someColors, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=days,
     labels=strftime(days, "%F"),
     tick=FALSE)
```

Comment: Algorithmic answers below are where the biggest speedup will come from, but I've found RJSONIO to be faster than rjson in some testing (and more reliable in parsing varied JSON structures). Might be worth trying that as well - usage is identical.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I picked pretty much arbitrarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a 40x speedup by using `plyr`. Here is the code and the benchmarking comparison. The conversion to date can be done once you have the data frame and hence I have removed it from the code to facilitate apples-to-apples comparison. I am sure a faster solution exists.

```
f_ramnath = function(n) plyr::ldply(trades[1:n], unlist)[,-c(1, 2)]
f_dustin  = function(n) do.call(rbind, lapply(trades[1:n], 
                function(row) data.frame(
                    date   = unlist(row$key)[2],
                    price  = unlist(row$value)[1],
                    volume = unlist(row$value)[2]))
                )
f_mrflick = function(n) as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(trades[1:n], 
               function(x){
                   list(date=x$key[2], price=x$value[1], volume=x$value[2])})))

f_mbq = function(n) data.frame(
          t(sapply(trades[1:n],'[[','key')),    
          t(sapply(trades[1:n],'[[','value')))

rbenchmark::benchmark(f_ramnath(100), f_dustin(100), f_mrflick(100), f_mbq(100),
    replications = 50)

test            elapsed   relative 
f_ramnath(100)  0.144       3.692308     
f_dustin(100)   6.244     160.102564     
f_mrflick(100)  0.039       1.000000    
f_mbq(100)      0.074       1.897436
```

EDIT. MrFlick's solution leads to an additional 3.5x speedup. I have updated my tests.

Comment: cool. let us know the speedup you obtained when processing 100k rows! would be useful to know

Comment: Note on the mbq one:  It should probably at least extract the date column, even though we're post-processing the strptime.

Comment: it does. you can check by running `f_mbq(10)` to see that it does return the date column

Comment: Oh, I see what it's doing now.  I'm probably learning more R from this question than any material I've learned yet.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I received another transformation by MrFlick in irc that was significantly faster and worth mentioning here:

```
data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
                              lapply(trades,
                                     function(x) {list(date=x$key[2],
                                                   price=x$value[1],
                                                   volume=x$value[2])})))
```

It seems to be made significantly faster by not building the inner frames.

Comment: yes. his solution is 3.5x faster than mine. i have updated my benchmark comparisons. it would be nice if you can `unaccept` my answer so that we get faster solutions!!

Comment: I can't accept my data just yet, but yours is a really great analysis including all the variations.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing vectorized operations on single elements, which is very inefficient. Price and volume can be extracted like this:

```
t(sapply(trades,'[[','value'))
```

And dates like this:

```
strptime(sapply(trades,'[[','key')[c(F,T)],'%FT%X')
```

Now only some sugar and the complete code looks like this:

```
data.frame(
 strptime(sapply(trades,'[[','key')[c(F,T)],'%FT%X'),
 t(sapply(trades,'[[','value')))->data
names(data)<-c('date','price','volume')
```

On my notebook, the whole set gets converted in about 0.7s, while 10k first rows (10%) take circa 8s using the original algorithm.

Comment: nice approach, but the solution by mrflick still trumps this by around 2x

Comment: @Ramnath Try benchmarking on larger data. Even in your a bit suboptimal implementation my version overtakes mrflick's for about 500 rows, and is slightly less 1.5x faster on the full set.

Comment: @Ramnath On my machine using `as.data.frame` in mbq's solution makes it fastest even on only 100 rows, and the margin grows quite a bit as you use more rows.

Comment: @joran. interesting. any thoughts no how the results would vary so much. this brings to question any benchmarking test reported since it varies widely with problem size and machinge configuration.

Comment: @mbq. yes for 500 rows your solution is significantly faster. this leads me to the question, how should one go about benchmarking different approaches when there is so much variation based on problem size and machine configuration.

Comment: @Ramnath Quite simple, you must just asses complexity =) Seriously, this can be done quite well by looking at computational time for several parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Is batching an option? Process 1000 rows at a time perhaps depending on how deep your json is. Do you really need to transform all the data? I am not sure about r and what exactly you are dealing with, but I am thinking of a generic approach.

Also do take a look at this: http://jackson.codehaus.org/ : A High-performance JSON processor.

Comment: Well, anything that works is fine, but I wouldn't expect ~100k rows to be all that hard to perform some of transformation on.  I do need all of the resulting data at once for the plot, though.  The rows are pretty much what you see there:  date, price, volume.  There's a bunch of JSON around it due to the source, but the source is *really* convenient as is.

Comment: cant you just keep updating the plot with the batches of json that you generate?

Comment: I don't know, but honestly, that *feels* unnecessary.  Reading the JSON takes a couple of seconds.  Generating the complete plot takes about a second.  Taking the JSON data and converting it to the thing I can feed into the `smoothScatter` takes a few minutes.  It seems that there must be another way.

Comment: ok.. somethings that you want to check, make sure your file read isnt slowing down things..