# Performance issues formatting using .json()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to load data from a file located at some URL. I use requests to get it (this happens plenty fast). However, it takes about 10 minutes to use r.json() to format part of the dictionary. How can I speed this up?

```
match_list = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    r = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches%d.json' % i)
    print('matches %d of 10 loaded' % i)
    match_list.append(r.json()['matches'])
    print('list %d of 10 created' % i)
match_histories = {}
match_histories['matches'] = match_list
```

I know that there is a related question here: [Performance problem transforming JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044313/performance-problem-transforming-json-data) , but I don't see how I can apply that to my case. Thanks! (I'm using Python 3).

Edit:

I have been given quite a few suggestions that seem promising, but with each I hit a roadblock.

- I would like to try cjson, but I cannot install it (pip can't find MS visual C++ 10.0, tried using some installation using Lua, but I need cl in my path to begin; ).
- json.loads(r.content) causes a TypeError in Python 3.
- I'm not sure how to get ijson working.
- ujson seems to take about as long as json
- json.loads(r.text.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')) takes just as long too

Comment: Are you sure it is the json conversion specifically that is taking time?  When I try this I'm finding that even `r.content` takes a long time.  From what I see the response content is about 19MB.  Creating a 19MB string will take a long time, even if you don't try to then parse it as json.

Comment: Eh, 19MB is teensy. But I do see that `json.load` doesn't see it as valid JSON, so `json.loads(r.content)` raises `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`. I'd bet that `r.json()` is spending a lot of time in exception handling.

Comment: I had to decode the data as unicode to work with it: `data = json.loads(r.text.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I did not get the UnicodeDecode Error that you got. Did you do something special to see that error message? Any idea how to reduce the time spent exceptino handling?

Comment: He is probably using Python 2. You have to take special precautions with Unicode in Python 2.

Comment: Yeah, you're right: I'm in Python 2 and neglected the whole bytes-not-Unicode bit. Turns out the answer is simpler: stdlib's json package just isn't very fast.

Comment: I've updated my answer. See how that works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in JSON parser isn't particularly fast. I tried another parser, python-cjson, like so:

```
import requests
import cjson

r = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json')
print cjson.decode(r.content)
```

The whole program took 3.7 seconds on my laptop, including fetching the data and formatting the output for display.

**Edit:** Wow, we were all on the wrong track. `json` isn't slow; Requests's charset detection is painfully slow. Try this instead:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json')
r.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print json.loads(r.text)
```

The `json.loads` part takes 1.5s on my same laptop. That's still slower than `cjson.decode` (at only .62s), but may be fast enough that you won't care if this isn't something you run very frequently. Caveat: I've only benchmarked this on Python2 and it might be different on Python3.

**Edit 2:** It seems cjson doesn't install in Python3. That's OK: `json.loads` in this version only takes .54 seconds. Charset detection is still glacial, though, and commenting the `r.encoding = 'UTF-8'` still makes the test script run in O(eternal) time. If you can count on those files always being UTF-8 encoded, I think the performance secret is to put that information in your script so that it doesn't have to figure this out at runtime. With that boost, you don't need to bother with supplying your own JSON parser. Just run:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json')
r.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print r.json()
```

Comment: I'm torn! I want to vote +1 your answer for showing me the cjson library, but I don't want to vote your answer because you didn't show him how to encode the data as unicode.

Comment: This answer is very thorough, thanks. I am having trouble installing cjson. I just used pip to install ijson... however it cannot find cjson (sorry, I'm a bit new to programming and not familiar with the best way to make these kind of installations).

Comment: @nivixzixer Gah! How embarassing; you're right. BTW, `r.text` is the unicode version of `r.content`.

@Mark (How on earth did you get *that* username?!?) The package name is that whole string: python-cjson. Install it like "pip install python-cjson".

Comment: The `requests` module by default uses `simplejson` when you call `r.json()`, and here is [a link to benchmarking of `ujson`, `simplejson` and `json`](https://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2015/09/29/benchmark-python-json-libraries/). `ujson` actually works best for me in Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `requests` uses `simplejson` to decode the JSON.  If you just get the data with `r.content` and then use the builtin Python `json` library, `json.loads(r.content)` works very quickly.  It works by raising an error for invalid JSON, but that's better than hanging for a long time.

Comment: json.loads(r.content) right after setting r=requests.get(BLA....) causes TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'.

Comment: @Mark: Presumably you're running Python 3.  That error doesn't occur on Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a streaming JSON parser (take a look at [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/)). A streaming approach will increase your memory efficient for the parsing step, but your program may still be sluggish since you are storing a rather large dataset in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a pretty big file you have there and pure python code (I suspect the requests library doesn't use C bindings for JSON parsing) is often rather slow. Do you really need all the data? If you only need some parts of it, maybe you can find a faster way to find it or use a different API if it is available.

You could also try to use a faster JSON library by using a library like ujson: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson

I didn't try this one myself but it claims to be fast. You can then just call `ujson.loads(r.text)` to obtain your data.